# Do I need a CDN or can I just go with ngnix loadbalancer (cache)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, cdn

I have a system that will generate image optimization and resizing for a client who has a news portal with lots of pageviews. We will provide only the images to this portal, but users are all on the same country as the our server. The question is, whats the best strategy thinking about cost-benefit:

1. Route all(most) image traffic via some paid CDN
2. Setup an internal image server using nginx and a loadbalancer

Monthly we estimate a bandwidth of 11TB, with millions of requests. (images only)

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is not really appropriate for SO, as it is very broad and answers will be opinion-based. SO is for specific problems about programming, usually with some code involved. Please have a look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) guides for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a questions if it is possible or what is more cost efficient.

You need to calculate the costs based on many factors: Actual sizing of your servers. Amount of servers. Bandwith. Where are the servers located and much more.

It will be a lot of work to setup and maintain / monitor your own CDN probaly but sure you can do it.

I dont think that anybody can create this calculation for you. See the comment fro Rob. It is not realy a question for SO.